# remove_action('genesis_header','genesis_do_header') hook not working

Tags: theme-development, headers, genesis-theme-framework

I am trying to remove the default 'genesis_do_header' action from the genesis_header hook in order to format my own header layout; however, for some reason it is not working when I try to either inject it into my child theme's functions.php or header.php. The new function that I want does work, though I just end up with the header double-rendered with both the default and the new custom header :/ Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What action do you have that hooked to? Child theme loads first, so you can’t remove something that hasn’t been added yet.

Comment: That makes sense, but effectively I want it to render a custom header script instead of the genesis_do_header default action, which I would like to remove. I have attempted adjusting the priority value, but it does not seem to help much.

Comment: Typically you need to do the removal on the `after_setup_theme` action